# `hostname` result is different from "/etc/hostname" after upgrade

Tags: sudo, localhost, hostname, hosts

If I open a terminal windows in my graphical user interface, `hostname` command result is different from content of `/etc/hostname`:

```
me@ZyXEL1:~$ hostname
ZyXEL1
me@ZyXEL1:~$ cat /etc/hostname
N4010
me@ZyXEL1:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 N4010

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

and `sudo` command shows:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ZyXEL1: No such file or directory
```

In tty1, tty2 and ... the command prompt is `me@N4010:~$` instead of wrong one: `me@ZyXEL1:~$`, but `sudo` result is same as terminal window:

```
me@N4010:~$sudo
sudo: unable to resolve host ZyXEL1: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Unfortunately there are different ways to change the `hostname` in Linux. Not only between distributions, also between versions. May we could have a look at the command `sysctl kernel.hostname`from your GUI Terminal? If this is set to ZyXEL1, we need to investigate why it is different ... In the meantime you should be able to fix sudo with `127.0.1.2 ZyXEL1` in your `/etc/hosts` file.

Answer (score 1):

By searching the web, I found that the problem is caused by my wireless modem/router because it is a ZyXEL ADSL2+ modem/router. I do not know why this problem was not seen before this, but the solution that prevents (at least in my case) this unattended host name change is to change `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` so that the system does not request `hostname` from DHCP server (that is running on wireless modem/router).

Run

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
```

Find a line similar to below command and coment it out:

```
send host-name = gethostname()
```

then find a `request` command that asks for `hostname`. it should be a line similar to:

```
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
```

In the list of parameters in front of `request` command find `host-name` and delete it.